# display a value only if none of the dependent values are nul

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

[image]

I am quite new to SQL and would need some suggestions to write a query to *select the value of Col1 only if none of the value of status of Col2 (Col3) is null in plsql.*
In the above, I am expecting the result to return only A2 as in A1, there is a null value in col3.

Comment: You said that you want to select COL1 "only if ..." (some condition is met). What do you want if that condition is not met? What would be desired result?

Comment: If condition not met, it should return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat but this should return you all the A2 rows:

```
select *
from yourTable d 
where d.col1 in (select col1
                 from (select col1
                             ,sum(case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end) null_values
                       from yourTable
                       group by col1
                      )
                 where null_values = 0
                )
```

To explain the approach briefly: The inner query counts the number of null col3 values for each col1 value; then the middle query returns the only the distinct col1 values having no associated null col3 values, and the outer query returns the all detail for all rows containing the col1 value.

The above is SQL of course. As you have specified PL/SQL, you could include something like a cursor or the *bulk collect into* clause as desired to work with the query result set.

As mentioned in my comment below, this is just one way of achieving the output - Oracle analytic functions may also prove helpful. Also depending on the size of your data set, you may want to consider the performance aspect of your chosen method.

Comment: So, in the above, as a result I am expecting the result to return only A2 as in A1 there is a null value in col3. Whereas, with your query, it will just omit a row of A1.

Comment: @Suchitra I have edited my answer to give you what I understand you to be after. Please note that there are many ways to deal with this - Oracle analytic functions for example may be of use here.

Comment: It worked and returned the expected result. Thank you so much for taking time out and helping me with this. :) currently, I am working on a way to optimize the query to get results a bit faster.